# Square-free zeta function zeros

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

It is a well known fact that the geometric series 
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$$
has the following form
$$\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Another possible representation  is
$$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)$$
This comes from  the identity
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{2^{k}}=\frac{1-x^{2^{k}+1}}{1-x}$$
now taking the numerator of the rhs we have
$$1-x^{2^{k}+1}=\left(1-x^{2^{k}}\right)\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)=\left(1-x^{2^{k}-1}\right)\left(1+x^{2^{k}-1}\right)\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)$$
proceeding this way we eventually get
$$\left(1-x\right)\left(1+x\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)\ldots\left(1+x^{2^{k}-2}\right)\left(1+x^{2^{k}-1}\right)\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)$$
Taking the limit for the geometric series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)$$
Now taking the zeta function
$$\zeta(z)=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{z}}+\frac{1}{p^{2z}}+\frac{1}{p^{3z}}+\ldots\right)$$
we can express it as 
$$\zeta(z)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\;\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{z\;2^{k}}}\right)$$

Now considere  for

$$G(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\;\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{z\;2^{k}}}\right)$$
note that now $k\geq 1$ and that $G(z)$ converges absolutely for $z>\frac{1}{2}$

**Can we say that, after analytic continuation, that**

$$H(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{^\infty}\frac{|\mu(k)|}{k^{z}}=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{z}}\right)$$ 
**has exactly the same zeros as $\zeta(z)$?**

Comment: How can you say that G(z) converges for $z > \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Roupa: because $w=2z,4z,8z,\ldots$.

Comment: what is $w$? And how do you say that the expression converges for $\Re(z) > \frac{1}{2}$? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @roupam, all the powers are multiples of a power of 2.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: $$ \sum \frac{|\mu(k)|}{k^z} = \frac{\zeta(z)}{\zeta(2z)} $$ for $\Re(z) > 1$

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series 
It might help you out.

Comment: where exactly do you think the answer is?

Comment: @Neves: You can factor $\sum \mu(n)^2 n^{-s}$ as the Euler product $\prod (1+p^{-s})$. To get the identity Roupam mentions, note that $1+x = (1-x^2)/(1-x)$ and then use the product of the original Riemann zeta function. Assuming RH, all zeros are therefore on $\zeta$'s critical line.